# how to enumerate OrderedDict in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ordereddictionary

So, I'm a php programmer who is trying to learn python. i have a dict of dict that i want sorted. I turned them into OrderedDict. They sort perfectly,
The original dict look like this. This is just a 3 dimensional array right?

```
a["01/01/2001"]["un"]=1
a["01/01/2001"]["nn"]=1
a["01/02/2001"]["aa"]=2
a["01/02/2001"]["bb"]=2
a["01/03/2001"]["zz"]=3
a["01/03/2001"]["rr"]=3
```

I can convert them into OrderedDict, and want to present them in the following format

```
"01/01/2001" un=1 nn=1
"01/02/2001" aa=2 bb=2
"01/03/2001" zz=3 rr=3
```

I can write a simple loop in php to go through this associative array, but i can't figure out how to do it in python. Could someone help?

Comment: OrderedDict does not mean "sorted dict". It means "preserve order of insertion of items into the dict", so they only are sorted if you insert them in sorted order. To *always* get dict in sorted key order, use `for key,value in sorted(dictvar.iteritems()):`, and there is no need for the overhead of an OrderedDict to be able to do this.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. So, how do i go about sorting a dictionary of dictionary a above, based on date, and present them in the format above? i'm so new to python, and am so confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop through the keys and values using the [`dict.items()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) or [`dict.iteritems()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) methods; the latter lets you iterate without building an intermediary list of key-value pairs:

```
for date, data in a.iteritems():
    print date,
    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        print '{}={}'.format(key, value),
    print
```

Looping directly over dictionaries gives you keys instead; you can still access the values by using subscription:

```
for date in a:
    print date,
    for key in a[date]:
        print '{}={}'.format(key, a[date][key]),
    print
```

Comment: i got an error saying:
    for key, value in data.iteritems():
    AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: @user2773013 It looks like `tld` is a function. In your original question, it seems that the variable `a` is the dictionary you're trying to iterate over. Try `a.iteritems()` instead.

Comment: @user2773013: What else have you stored in `a`? At least *one* of your values in `a` appears to be a function instead.

Comment: @user2773013: My code *does* assume that *all* values in `a` are dictionaries. It appears that that is not the case for your sample set.

Comment: a is OrderedDictionary converted using 
a=OrderedDict(something.items(),key = lambda x,y:(time.strptime(string.lower(x[0]),"%d/%b/%Y"),x[1]))

something is a dictionary of dictionary looking exactly like the variable a I mentioned above.

Comment: @user2773013: You are missing a `sorted()` call there. You added `('key': lambda x,y:(time.strptime(string.lower(x[0]),"%d/%b/%Y"),x[1]))` *to the dictionary*.

Comment: @user2773013: `a = OrderedDict(sorted(something.items(), key=lambda x,y: (time.strptime(string.lower(x[0]), "%d/%b/%Y"), x[1])))` is what you really want.

Comment: now, i'm getting: 
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
But it is 2 arguments! I

Comment: @user2773013: no, you are passed the `(key, value)` tuple as one argument. Just drop the `, y` argument and you are set, you already are sorting it according to the `x[0]` value.

Comment: So, corrected: =a = OrderedDict(sorted(something.items(), key=lambda x: (time.strptime(string.lower(x[0]), "%d/%b/%Y"), x[1])))`

Comment: okay, that works now. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! i'm so confused though. why do i need to drop the y? i thought i'm passing time.strptime(string.lower(x[0]), "%d/%b/%Y") 
AND x[1]. Isn't that two argument?

Comment: @user2773013: No, that's the lambda *body*, the result passed back.

Comment: @user2773013: The `sorted()` key function is passed each item being sorted as one argument.

Answer (score 2):

I think rather than OrderedDict, you will be better off with a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = defaultdict(dict)
a["01/03/2001"]["zz"]=3
a["01/01/2001"]["un"]=1
a["01/02/2001"]["aa"]=2
a["01/01/2001"]["nn"]=1
a["01/02/2001"]["bb"]=2
a["01/03/2001"]["rr"]=3

# a is now a dict of dicts, each key is a date and each value is a dict of all 
# subkey-values

# print out in date order
for k,v in sorted(a.items()):
    # for each subdict, print key=value in sorted key order
    print k, ' '.join("%s=%s" % (kk,vv) for kk,vv in sorted(v.items()))
```

Prints:

```
01/01/2001 nn=1 un=1
01/02/2001 aa=2 bb=2
01/03/2001 rr=3 zz=3
```

**EDIT:**

Ah! My bad, you want the k=v values shown in insertion order, so you need a defaultdict of OrderedDict's:

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict

a = defaultdict(OrderedDict)
a["01/01/2001"]["un"]=1
a["01/01/2001"]["nn"]=1
a["01/02/2001"]["aa"]=2
a["01/02/2001"]["bb"]=2
a["01/03/2001"]["zz"]=3
a["01/03/2001"]["rr"]=3

# print out in date order
for k,v in sorted(a.items()):
    # for each subdict, print key=value in as-inserted key order, so no sort requred
    print k, ' '.join("%s=%s" % (kk,vv) for kk,vv in v.items())
```

Prints:

```
01/01/2001 un=1 nn=1
01/02/2001 aa=2 bb=2
01/03/2001 zz=3 rr=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code.

```
a = {
        "01/01/2001": {"un": 1, "nn": 1}, \
        "01/02/2001": {"aa": 2, "bb": 2}, \
        "01/03/2001": {"zz": 3, "rr": 3}
    }

class decor(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __call__(self, fun):
        def wrapper(key, _list):
            print key, ' '.join(["{}={}".format(ele, self.a[key][ele]) \
                        for ele in _list
                    ])
            fun(key)
        return wrapper

@decor(a)
def main_fun(key):
    pass

for key in sorted(a.keys()):
    main_fun(key, [inner_key for inner_key in sorted(a[key].keys())])
```